# Separate POCO Object classes and DBContext from Entity Framework 6 Model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I started to use Entity Framework 6.0.1 version. I want to separate the generated DbContext and POCO template classes to different class library from the model. I spent a few hours solve the problem without any success.

If I create a new class library, add EF 6 EntityObject Generator and fill the following template variable:

`SourceCsdlPath = @"..\..\DataAccess\Model.edmx"`,

Get the following error in the error list after building:

> Error 2   Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Unable to locate file File name:
>   'C:\Source\EFsource\POCO....\DataAccess\SZOSZRDBModel.edmx'
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolvePath(String
>   path)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ITextTemplatingEngineHost.ResolvePath(String
>   path)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31479401930D2C4820ACF71C66B5389A24A5053726798D9718DB676B3FFA30A3454B3CB1EDE2E1C267D5278B1528860C072E81A0E4647BC23993669604048FCD.GeneratedTextTransformation.ApplyUserSettings(UserSettings
>   userSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31479401930D2C4820ACF71C66B5389A24A5053726798D9718DB676B3FFA30A3454B3CB1EDE2E1C267D5278B1528860C072E81A0E4647BC23993669604048FCD.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()

The Error message is clear, but i do not know, how to set Model path without full absolute path.

I am not sure, using newest version of entity framework is the best idea...

Comment: Did you want `@"\..\..\DataAccess\Model.edmx"`?

Comment: I do not understand your question. I want to set another folder of project, but i cannot navigate up in directory tree.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Absolute paths are not required.  It looks like your relative path is not correct.  I am using EF6.1 and I have the POCO classes in a separate project.  This is how I got it to work in VS 2013.

1. Created a Class Library Project and added an `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`. This project will contain the `DB Context`.
2. Added a new `EF6.x DbContext Generator` item to the `DBContext` project.
3. Created a new Class Library Project. This project will contain the `POCO` objects.
4. Moved the `[Project Name]Model.tt` file from the `DbContext` project to the `POCO` project.
5. Edited the `[Project Name]Model.tt` file. On line 5, I changed:
   `const string inputFile = @"SampleModel.edmx";`

   to:
   `const string inputFile = @"..\DbContext\SampleModel.edmx";`
6. Added a reference in the `DbContext` project to the `POCO` project.

If you are using VS 2013, you can debug the template to see how your relative path is being resolved.

1. Add a breakpoint to your `.tt` file.
2. Right-click the `.tt` file in the Solution Explorer and select "Debug T4 Template".

Comment: @fremis, your pocos do they have any base types like they do in EF4? In DB First approach, pocos generated are all marked as partial but doesn't look like they are derived from anything at all.

Comment: Ibar, my DTO don't inherit any class... the partial key word allows me to spread the definition of a class across multiple files.  When I need to regenerate my DTO's, the T4 template will overwrite the code generated files, but my "hand edited" file are not affected.  I edit the T4 template to generate files with the following naming convention: [class name].base.cs.  I then create classes named [class name].cs. The non-generated files will extend the "base" generated files with interfaces.  I can provide a concrete example if you are interested.

Comment: I think you also need to change the Custom Tool Namespace in the *.tt file properties to correspond to the default namespace in the project that contains edmx file.

Comment: The `DbContext` project requires a reference to the `POCO` project, but then if the `POCO` project wants to do anything useful, it'll have to reference the `DbContext` project which results in a circular dependency which is not allowed. I guess your `POCO project is just another sub-project within your application project.

Comment: Also, for those struggling with getting the inputFile path correct in the .tt file: the System.IO.FileNotFoundException error will show immediately in your Error window, if you click Save on the .tt file with an incorrect path. Keep tweaking your path until the error doesn't display on Save. Then, you'll know you've got the path correct.