# separate entity framework 6 entities into separate class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework-6, edmx

i have followed the steps in this question 
[Separate POCO Object classes and DBContext from Entity Framework 6 Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317913/separate-poco-object-classes-and-dbcontext-from-entity-framework-6-model)

and i'm done with that, and every thing works good. but my problem is each time i made some changes on the model (edmx) file, the changes do not affect the .tt file, so i go and just save the .tt file to update the mapped classes .

any help please.

Comment: Saving the edmx file is usually all you need to do to force a regeneration of the entity POCOs. The .tt files shouldn't actually be changing, just the classes generated by them. The classes don't update on the fly with changes made in the edmx file.

Comment: so i need to do this process manual, right??

Comment: If by manually you mean saving the edmx then yes. Building the project will also trigger the update as it automatically saves the edmx file. This is just the way the edmx file is designed. I fear running the .tt files in real time to sync the entities up with what is currently in the edmx file would be painfully slow. You shouldn't have to manually edit anything that is generated by the edmx file, and you really shouldn't as the next time the EntityDeploy action is run it will overwrite the changes anyway.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't the exact answer you were looking for, but the file is what it is.