# How to make Entity Generator put classes in different files

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a model.edmx generated from DB.

When I Add Code Generation Item -> ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator,
a Model.tt file is created with partial classes for every table in the model.

1. How can I make the generator separate the classes to different files?
2. Can I edit these partial classes? (Change names of the properties, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20331742/1505865) might be useful to you.

Comment: They are using a T4 template. I don't have it.

Comment: ... yes you have. The generated .tt file is a T4 template.

Comment: So what's the procedure for separating the classes from the .tt cs file?